# How to gracefully handle exceptions in a Sinatra API

Tags: ruby, exception, sinatra

I'm trying to write an API in Sinatra that accepts a temporary CSV file as a parameter. I want to raise an exception if the filetype isn't text/csv or if the CSV doesn't have an email column, and I wanted the confirmation page to simply display the error message. I imagined it to look something like this:

```
if params[:recipients_file]
  raise ArgumentError, 'Invalid file. Make sure it is of type text/csv.' unless params[:recipients_file][:type] == "text/csv"
  recipients_csv = CSV.parse(params[:recipients_file][:tempfile].read, {headers: true})
  raise ArgumentError, 'Invalid CSV. Make sure it has an "email" column' unless recipients_csv.headers.include?('email')
  recipients += recipients_csv.map {|recipient| recipient["email"]}
end
```

However, any time one of those conditions isn't met, I get really ugly error messages like `NoMethodErrors` etc. I just want the API to stop execution and to return the error message on the confirmation page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You should define an `error` block:

```
error do
  env['sinatra.error'].message
end
```

See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error for more details, including how to set up different error handlers for different exception types, HTTP status codes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. First, you should add this line of code in your main app.rb or server.rb(whatever the name of your file) so that it will catch your error block below.

`set :show_exceptions, false`

Step 2. The exception object can be obtained from the sinatra.error Rack variable. To catch all error then add this error block e.g. `code error do...`

```
error do
  env['sinatra.error'].message
end
```